# dynamic height of a pdf

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, vuejs2

I am trying to show a pdf, I am doing it with an iframe, but what I want to achieve is that the pdf that I show, the height is that of the document, that is to say that in the pdf viewer the height is that of the 3 pages so that the user has to read the document before seeing the text below.
How can I do it?

this is a very basic example that I did [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/jesusdelrioc/pen/VwpgNXr)

also say that I work with vue, and this would be to integrate it in vue

Comment: @KJ Thank you, I didn't explain it well, but what I want to achieve is that the scroll of the viewer disappears, and that where you have to scrooll is on the page, that's why I ask how I could make the pdf viewer be as high than the whole pdf.

Answer (score 0):

One posible solution although not "dynamic" is to set height to encompass the given 3 pages which in this case I opted for 1970px loosely based on A4 at 500px wide = 706px high and would thus need about 2118px height, but in practice 1970 appears more than enough for the 3 given pages (you can fine tune that on a case by case basis)

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<div class="box">
  <iframe id="iframe1" src="https://ana.mareca.es/wp-content/plugins/algori-pdf-viewer/dist/web/viewer.html?file=https%3A%2F%2Fana.mareca.es%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2020%2F05%2FPdf-de-prueba-con-varias-paginas.pdf#view=fit"
      width="100%" height="1970px"></iframe>
</div>

<h3>I confirm that I have read the 3 pages</h3>
```